# SimpleDraweeView round corners in XML

Tags: android, fresco

I'm trying to round specific corners of image using Fresco lib.

As shown in the pic, how to round the bottom left corner of the image.

[image]

Here is the xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="4.0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="8.0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="8.0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4.0dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
>

<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@color/pink"
    fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
    fresco:roundBottomRight="false"
    fresco:roundTopRight="false"
    fresco:roundBottomLeft="true"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: check your question its not clear what you want to do

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi I think I've stated it clearly, how to round bottom left corner of the image

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi Yup it was typo mistake, I've updated it now. Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your image is going out of your `CardView` area and that is creating problem.

You can try out by giving your `CardView` height as `wrap_content` and give slight `padding_left` and `padding_bottom` to `SimpleDraweeView`

Answer (score 11):

If you have in your parent layout `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and `xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` use

```
app:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
```

instead

```
fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
```

Comment: easiest way. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `CardView`.

Use following lines, according to your requirement:

```
fresco:roundTopLeft="true"  
fresco:roundTopRight="false"
fresco:roundBottomLeft="false"
fresco:roundBottomRight="true"
fresco:roundTopStart="false"
fresco:roundTopEnd="false"
fresco:roundBottomStart="false"
fresco:roundBottomEnd="false"
```

For [reference](https://frescolib.org/docs/using-simpledraweeview.html)